# Docker ps Shows the container Docker stop says Invalid

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am trying to stop a docker container which is running

```html
docker ps
shows the container is running 

docker exec -it <containerId> bash
says the container is invalid

`docker stats <containerName>
<ContainerName>      0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0.00%               0 B / 0 B           0 B / 0 B           0


and running below commands gives a PID which is not running on the machine
 docker inspect <copntainerName> | grep Pid
```

`
BUT
running docker ps gives me the container is running

Can you tell me how to stop/mark(stopped) this container? I understand the container is not running but the docker machine thinks its running

i mean its not about "real data", about the status of the docker container

docker ps

when I execute docker stop 
it says invalid

from docker inspect  i found the processId , which is not running when I gave ps -eaf

which means the container status is wrong with the docker machine

Docker version used 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Answer (score 2):

Start with [`docker container stop`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_stop/).
If it isn't enough [docker container kill](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_kill/) can help sending a kill message.

In both cases, check the result with `docker ps -a`.

Comment: even the kill does not stop, I believe it is actually stopped but somehow docker-machine is not able to sync that data

Comment: though the container is stopped since the inspect gave me a PID which does not exist on the linux machine

but docker ps still Retuns that it is running

Comment: @Purna docker-machine? You did not mention anything about docker-machine or "data synchronisation" in your question... Can you edit your question to add what is your actual issue? Also what docker version are you using? On which host OS? With which VM?

Comment: i mean its not about "real data", about the status of the docker container

docker ps 
<lists my container>

when I execute docker stop <container>
it says invalid 

from docker inspect <ContainerId> i found the processId , which is not running when I gave ps -eaf 

which means the container status is wrong with the docker machine 

Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Comment: @Purna As long as the container is marked "Exited", you will find a process id associated to it, I suspect.  On which host OS are you running docker? With which VM?

Comment: its running on AWS as EC2 instance (ubuntu)